# ARC welder for chrome is not launching properly

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

I am using chrome developer version 63.0.3239.70. I just added ARC Welder from chrome web store. On launching its showing following screen. (blank)

[ARC Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsWsi.png)

Comment: Hey @Himanshu welcome to stack overflow when you are posting any question you need to show your effort how much you achieve so you need to post code what you done.

Comment: @Dilip one image is there. i just added ARC Welder to chrome. I think code is not required for this. Even google suggests that it ll ask for a directory and i am getting a blank screen.

Comment: I have a user that is experiencing the same problem.  I reinstalled it on my computer and it is working just fine.  I have no idea why it isn't working for them.  Hopefully someone can figure out the answer.

Comment: @StephenRuda even i reinstalled it, but its not working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the latest version of Chrome.  It was working for me and then I updated Chrome to the latest version and it stopped working.  It seems that a few things got deprecated.  It should work if you use a version of Chrome 62.x or lower.  I believe the deprecation starts with Chrome 63.x.  This will not work on the newer versions of Chrome until they update the extension (if ever).

Here is some error output:

> [Deprecation] /deep/ combinator is no longer supported in CSS dynamic profile.It is now effectively no-op, acting as if it were a descendant combinator. /deep/ combinator will be removed, and will be invalid at M65. You should remove it. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4964279606312960 for more details.
>   index.js:17096 [Deprecation] Calling Element.createShadowRoot() for an element which already hosts a shadow root is deprecated and will be removed in M63, around December 2017. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4668884095336448 for more details.
>   shadowFromTemplate @ index.js:17096